Beamer presentation with markdown + pandoc, Navigation sidebar
I'm trying to create a beamer presentation using pandoc + markdown. I want a sidebar that displays the sections of my presentation.
Something like this (desired output, not mine):

If I click on any of the links in the sidebar, it takes me to that section, which isn't necessarily named like the thing in the sidebar.
I've come up with this after some digging in the beamer documentation and net:
---
title: "Your Presentation Title"
author: "Your Name"
date: "October 2024"
output: beamer
header-includes:
    - \usetheme{Berkeley}
    - \usecolortheme{sidebartab}{\insertsectionnavigation}
---

# Introduction

This slide provides an introduction to the topic.

# Functions

## What are Functions?

A function is a block of code that performs a specific task.

Corresponding pandoc code:
pandoc -t beamer -o beamer.tex testing_beamer_themes.md -s --mathml

However this only displays the title and author in the sidebar, not the frames.

Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show the resulting TeX code? Did you get error messages?

\usecolortheme does not look like the right command to add structural information into the side-bar.

@Mensch , the resulting TeX code doesnt show any errors upon compiling , in overleaf atleast

@PuzzleheadedSoup-98 The \usecolortheme{sidebartab}{\insertsectionnavigation} will definitely cause an error, overleaf unfortunately is just good at hiding errors. Always check the top right corner for the tiny red square.

The sidebar shows sections and subsections, not frames. Add a (sub-)section before each of your frames and you'll see them in the sidebar:
---
title: "Your Presentation Title"
author: "Your Name"
date: "October 2024"
output: beamer_presentation
header-includes:
    - \usetheme{Berkeley}
    - \AtBeginSection[]{}
    - \AtBeginSubsection[]{}    
---

# Big Section
## Introduction
### Introduction


This slide provides an introduction to the topic.

# Functions
### Functions

#### What are Functions?

A function is a block of code that performs a specific task.



this works ! but how would i add subsections in the sidebar ? something like "types of relations" under "Relations on Sets" in the pic i uploaded

Use ## whatever to add a subsection and then increase the level of all the following headings by one.

pandoc is rendering anything after the title of the slide as a phantomsection instead of subsection : \phantomsection\label{what-are-functions-expected-as-subsection} . Correcting it to subsection manually works , but is there a way to make it subsection in markdown ?

@PuzzleheadedSoup-98 I updated the example to use a subsection for the intro

thank you ! this works perfectly!

@PuzzleheadedSoup-98 You're welcome!
